# Godef not being found in a go-mode emacs session

Tags: go, emacs

I have godef installed via

```
go get github.com/rogpeppe/godef
```

I have emacs go-mode installed, and the following exports in my .bashrc:

```
export GOROOT=/usr/local/go
export GOPATH=$HOME/go
export PATH=$GOPATH/bin:$GOROOT/bin:$PATH
```

godef is found in the sense that

```
godef -h # appears to work.
```

As in:

```
$ godef -h
usage: godef [flags] [expr]
  -A    print all type and members information
  -a    print public type and member information
  -acme
        use current acme window
  -debug
        debug mode
  -f string
        Go source filename
  -i    read file from stdin
  -json
        output location in JSON format (-t flag is ignored)
  -o int
        file offset of identifier in stdin (default -1)
  -t    print type information
```

When I run `C-c C-d` in a file in my emacs session, which should be calling a `godef-describe` function per

https://github.com/dominikh/go-mode.el

I expect:

```
Integration with godef

    godef-describe (C-c C-d) to describe expressions
    godef-jump (C-c C-j) and godef-jump-other-window (C-x 4 C-c C-j) to jump to declarations
    This requires you to install godef via go get github.com/rogpeppe/godef.
```

Cool, all set. But when I try to use C-c C-d in a go file, I get:

```
Could not run godef binary
```

I can run it on the command line, and it appears properly defined.  What's happening?

I find:

```
M-x godoc

// then
godoc: OSReadDir // for example
```

Produces

```
godoc: /bin/bash: go: command not found
```

Which suggests to me that even though godef and godoc are found in an ordinary shell, there may be some path issue within emacs?  How can I check or fix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's this again:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1045712/emacs-launched-from-favorites-doesnt-read-bashrc

If you launch emacs from the Ubuntu launcher, it doesn't load .bashrc.

You have to open a terminal, and call

```
$ emacs
```

The emacs that pops up will have inherited your .bashrc from your shell.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

~/.emacs.d/init.el

```
(setq exec-path (append exec-path '("/root/go/bin")))
```

Answer (score 0):

For those running into this error while on OSX, adding

```
export GOROOT=/usr/local/go
export GOPATH=$HOME/go
export PATH=$GOPATH/bin:$GOROOT/bin:$PATH
```

to `~/.bash_profile` did the trick for me